# Setting tab-space style in Visual Studio Code... accordingly to the project type

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, indentation

How can I set the tab-to-space indentation conversion in VSCode? For instance, when I press the Tab key, I want it to produce 4 spaces.

BUT **WAIT** before you jump to the answer straight away... I know this kind of config questions has probably been asked many times here, but I want to ask this question slightly differently here. Please bear with me.

I know there is a "guess" option somewhere in config of VSCode, but instead of having VSCode to "guess" per file, I want to set it such that when I am doing **Python-related projects**, it will produce 4 spaces... but when I am doing other projects with VSCode - files like HTML, JavaScript, PHP, XML, etc, I want it to produce normal tabs.

Is that possible? Since I switch to different kind of projects a lot, I just don't want to switch/modify config files all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to File > Preferences > Settings. User Settings should pop up. Add the following:

```
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    },
```

Comment: Thanks... and I guess I have to have "editor.insertSpaces": true/false under different file types for inserting tabs/spaces? And.... are there an "others" file type?

Comment: @user2526586 .I don't think a wildcard exists for others. But you can view all supported languages by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + P`, then run this command, **Preferences: Configure language specific settings...** Select the language you want and move on.